# Функция принимающая в себя разные типы данных

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Я новичок и только недавно начал изучать программирование поэтому прошу не бейте палками если я делаю что-то не так)
Собственно в чём проблема:
Я недавно проходил функции, прототипы функций, параметры функции по умолчанию, перегрузку функций и шаблоны функций.
Во время изучения этих материалов у меня встал вопрос можно ли в c++ как-либо реализовать такую функцию которая работала бы с несколькими типами данных одновременно (в качестве примера чтобы ничего не усложнять в вопросе я взял простое сложение)
Если реализовать через перегрузку:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int foo(int a, int b)
{
    return(a + b);
}

double foo(double a, double b)
{
    return(a + b);
}

int main()
{
    //setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
    cout << foo(1, 1) << endl;
    cout << foo(1.5, 1.5) << endl;
    cout << foo(1, 1.5) << endl; //не работает т.к. можно использовать сразу две функции
}
```

Можно конечно добавить больше перегрузок и сделать отдельные функции для int double и double int
но мне кажется что это не правильно, громоздко и не удобно.
Если реализовывать через шаблоны:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <typename T1, typename T2>
T1 foo(T1 = a, T2 = b) 
{
    return(a + b);
}

int main()
{
    cout << foo(1, 1) << endl;
    cout << foo(1.5, 1.5) << endl;
    cout << foo(1, 1.5) << endl; //не работает правильно т.к. ответ приводится к типу первого аргумента
}
```

Comment: ¿Так а вопрос-то в чем?

Comment: А вопрос-то в чем? Кстати, шаблон написан не совсем верно, мягко говоря. Проблема с возвращаемым типом. (знаки `=` сочтем опиской).

Comment: можно ли в c++ как-либо реализовать такую функцию которая работала бы с несколькими типами данных одновременно без костылей которые я привёл выше

Comment: Совсем любыми? Складывать, например, строки с числами? Или только арифметические? Кстати, напишите только одну foo(double,double), и она будет суммировать все три ваши варианта :) И что считать *костылем*?...

Comment: Ну не то чтобы совсем с любыми, я привёл примеры только на int и double, мне бы хотя бы понять как это решить. И я вроде знаю что c++ строго типизированный язык программирования и строки с числами нельзя складывать просто так.
Суть вопроса была немного в другом - как сделать так чтобы функция нормально считала оба типа данных и не нужно было писать много лишних перегрузок под каждый тип (в первом примере описана проблема)

Comment: Если это очень подобный код — можно сделать шаблон (только сделать его правильно). Если код существенно разный — лучше перегрузки. imho.

Comment: >>foo(double,double). Ну это сейчас я могу обойтись одной функцией с аргументами double double, а в случае если у меня в будущем будут пользовательские типы, или функция будет работать с чем-либо что требует больших ресурсов?

Comment: а если вот так написать функцию `template <typename T1, typename T2>
auto foo(T1  a, T2 b) `? похоже это то, что Вы ищите

Comment: У вас предельно неконкретные вопросы. В каждом конкретном случае выбирается тот вариант, который лучше решает поставленную задачу, который понятнее, дает меньше ошибок, наконец, просто привычнее или проще для написания... Единого решения нет. Вы же не мечтаете, чтобы все ходили в костюмах одного цвета и покроя? :) Так почему вы хотите напялить одну одежду на все программы?

Comment: Если хотите, чтобы типы аргументов получались одинаковыми, то и используйте один параметр шаблона `template<typename T> T foo(T a, T b) `

Comment: >>выбирается тот вариант, который лучше решает поставленную задачу. А если мне нужна универсальность? Хотя теперь мне уже действительно кажется что лучше под каждую определённую ситуацию писать код который будет лучше всего её решать

Comment: >>auto
Да это кажется именно то что я искал :)
Спасибо большое всем кто потратил своё время на помощь)

Comment: так, это я третий раз уже за сегодня угадал мысли:)

Comment: @KoVadim А я все ждал, когда ТС спросит "а что вы имели в виду под *сделать шаблон (только сделать его правильно)*?"

Comment: хехе)
Кстати как я могу Ваш ответ выбрать лучшим или поднять вам рейтинг? Я впервые на stackoverflow и не вижу сейчас где это сделать, возможно я не туда смотрю или смотрю плохо...

Comment: голосовать можно за ответы, а вот за комментарии - чуточку сложновато:)

Comment: Да тут непонятно, как ответ-то написать. Комментарии - да, а вот ответ... Конкретного-то вопроса нет. И, кстати, вот — https://ideone.com/w7nJQm

Answer (score 3):

В целом, сделать то, что хочется, немного сложно - ведь для разных типов будут разные способы сделать "сложение". Как упомянули в коментариях, сложить строку и число может быть немного затруднительно. Даже javascript решает задачу иногда оригинально странно, вместо просто показать ошибку. Но перейдем к нашей теме.

Когда типы одинаковые, то вопросов не возникает, а вот если типы разные, то нужен какой то один общий тип. И чудо, в стандартной библиотеке есть готовый функционал - [common_type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/common_type), где есть даже пример. Но я адаптирую Ваш

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
typename std::common_type<T1, T2>::type foo(T1  a, T2 b) 
{
    return a + b;
}
```

И в этом случае, мы доверяем компилятору подобрать правильный тип.

Но у этого способа есть недостаток - он хорошо работает для арифметических типов, но плохо для каких-то пользовательских типов, для которых компилятор не может вывести общий тип. Но компилятор может его "угадать", если он может сложить типы. Самый простой способ - это просто написать auto и компилятор сам все сделает.

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
auto foo(T1  a, T2 b) 
{
    return a + b;
}
```

Но если компилятор поддерживает только с++11, то этот способ не поможет, поэтому, можно подсказать компилятору:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
auto foo(T1  a, T2 b)  -> decltype(a+b)
{
    return a + b;
}
```

в этом случае мы просто говорим компилятору - посмотри на выражение `a+b`, выведи его тип самостоятельно и используй. Но это может понадобиться и для "новых крутых компиляторов". В некоторых случаях, если кол-во return больше одного, а типы в них получаются разные, то компилятор имеет право сказать "извени, я тут не могу" и указанный способ как раз и нужен - обычно программист лучше знает, что ему нужно.

Но у этого кода есть одна "бяка". Посмотрите на такой вызов

```
std::cout << foo("bar", "baz");
```

такой код не компилируется с кучей ошибок. Один из способов пофикисить - это дописать вот так

```
// не складывайте указатели на константные строки!!!
const char* foo(const char*, const char*) = delete;
```

теперь ошибка будет более явной.

Но все таки, тут есть способ написать нормальный оператор сложения, но это уже домашнее задание со звездочкой.

Comment: Непонятно зачем удалять перегрузку с двумя строками. С тем же успехом можно положиться на SFINAE в `-> decltype(a+b)`.

Comment: ну я же объяснил. Можно не удалять. В этом случае это может не очень очевидно, но  иногда компиляторы выдают такие портянки ошибок, что даже опытные специалисты пробиваются через простыни. А такая штука очень сильно сокращает вывод и самое главное, можно добавить комментарий/ссылку на локальную документацию, где объяснить, почему это так сделано.